# Image selection limit while picking images from the gallery

Tags: android, kotlin

How to set a limit for selecting images in gallery. I want to select atmost 5 images. My project is in kotlin android. can someone help?

Comment: what youve tried so far ?

Comment: @P.Juni tried with image count. But now i need to show the warning message like "image selection limit is 5" while picking before 6th image

Comment: what I meant is show what you tried so far

Comment: val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
                        // var intent = Intent(Intent.CATEGORY_APP_GALLERY)
                        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true)
                        intent.action = Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT
                        intent.putExtra(Intent.CATEGORY_APP_GALLERY,true)
                        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
                        intent.type = "image/*"

                        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_MULTIPLE);

Comment: There is nothing built into Android that gives you this option. You will need to develop your own image picker or use some third-party library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this library it good for multiple image selector or you can set  max image selection https://github.com/zfdang/android-multiple-images-selector